# Trouble syncing my QT bitcoin wallet 12 days already and 144 weeks to go

Tags: synchronization

I have been syncing my QT 8.5 beta bitcoin wallet for 12days and it has 142 weeks to go there must be something wrong it started at 160 weeks.

What can I do about it at this rate it my take 3 months
I sent a bitcoin when it was syncing small amount when though but larger amount don't. On other sites it said you can send when its syncing but I now know you can not.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5112/is-there-a-way-to-access-my-bitcoins-before-bitcoin-qt-syncs

Comment: Also related (but currently doesn't have an answer, unfortunately): https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/sync-with-bitcoin-qt-very-slow-0-01

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade your wallet to the latest version of Bitcoin Core (it's the same thing as bitcoin-qt). Bitcoin-qt 0.8.5 beta is extremely old and unlikely to be able to actually sync the Bitcoin blockchain. Install the latest version of [Bitcoin Core from bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/download) and let it sync the rest of the blockchain. Upgrading to the new version will not remove any blockchain or wallet data so it will use what you have already downloaded.

Comment: so i will not loss my bitcoins

Comment: No, you will not lose any Bitcoin

Comment: what is the steps needed after i download the latest version

Comment: Install and run bitcoin core. Everything else is done automatically by the software

Comment: Hi Andrew i have do what you said its been 2 full days and it has become very slow its only half way done 51%  Its taken a day to go from 47% to 51% is this normal  or is there a problem?

Comment: Syncing the blockchain can take a long time and is dependent on your hardware. Taking multiple days to sync the blockchain is not abnormal.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be because your computer is slow validating the blockchain but not necessarily. This [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/69862/75001) may help you.